# Split("", "|") returns 1 item

Tags: vb.net, split, string-function

When I do the following....

```
    Dim s As String = ""
    Dim sLines() As String = s.Split("|", StringSplitOptions.None)
```

...

sLines.Count is 1.

Why?

There is nothing to split, and the string to be split is empty, so I would expect sLines.Count to be 0.

Thank you.

Comment: What are the contents of `sLines` ?

Comment: If Expression is a zero-length string (""), Split returns a single-element array containing a zero-length string. from here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: @fukanchik - the reference you provided is for the Split function.  The poster is using the Split.Method.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sort of consistency: if `"a|b"` split on `|` is [`"a"`, `"b"`] and `"a"` split on `|` is [`"a"`], it makes some sense for `"|b"` split on `|` to be [`""`, `"b"`] and `""` split on `|` to be [`""`].

You can remove *all* empty entries by passing `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` instead of `None`, or just check for `s = String.Empty` manually otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Check the documentation of [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If this instance does not contain any of the strings in separator, the returned array consists of a single element that contains this instance.

This is your case. `""` doesn't contain `"|"`, so a single element `""` is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IIf()` function to handle empty string

```
 Dim s As String = ""
 Dim sLines() As String = IIf(s = String.Empty, Nothing, s.Split("|"))
 Dim cnt As Integer
 If sLines IsNot Nothing Then
    'your code
    cnt = sLines.Count
 Else
    'your code
     cnt = 0
 End If
```

*Note:* In case if you want to handle white spaces(`Dim s As String = " "`) just use `trim()` like this

`IIf(Trim(s) = String.Empty, Nothing, s.Split("|"))`